# Total members limit?

Tags: members

I have a site using EE 2.5.2, they have a count of the total members of the site on the homepage using:

```
{member_total}
```

The site has recently gone over 10,000 members and the counter has gone back to 0 and started counting up from 0 again.

Am I correct in assuming there's a limit of 9999 members that the tag can process and is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out {member_total} was correctly counting the total members at over 10,000, the font was just the same as the background colour, so the last digit was just hidden.